# Erro ao trazer informações do banco de dados

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou tendo problemas para trazer as informações do banco de dados e exibi-los em uma lista, quando se executa o código pra trazer as informações do BD a aplicação para e o seguinte erro aparece:

## Stack Trace

---

- FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.matheus.privatewalletm, PID: 3515
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
  'void
  android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
  on a null object reference
                                                                                       at
  com.example.matheus.privatewalletm.UsuarioAdapter.getView(UsuarioAdapter.java:60)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at
  android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                                                       at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                       at
  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                       at
  android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                       at
  android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

## ----

### Classes Envolvidas

Classe `Novo`:

```
public class Novo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Usuario usuario;
    private EditText editTextNome;
    private EditText editTextData;
    private EditText editTextRg;
    private EditText editTextCpf;
    private EditText editTextDoenca;
    private EditText editTextAlergia;
    private EditText editTextProfissao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo);

        this.usuario = new Usuario();
        this.editTextNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
        this.editTextData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
        this.editTextRg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRg);
        this.editTextCpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCpf);
        this.editTextDoenca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDoenca);
        this.editTextAlergia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAlergia);
        this.editTextProfissao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProfissao);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
            if(intent != null){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if(bundle != null){
                    this.usuario.setId(bundle.getInt("id"));
                    this.editTextNome.setText(bundle.getString("nome"));
                    this.editTextData.setText(bundle.getInt("data"));
                    this.editTextRg.setText(bundle.getString("rg"));
                    this.editTextCpf.setText(bundle.getString("cpf"));
                    this.editTextDoenca.setText(bundle.getString("doenca"));
                    this.editTextAlergia.setText(bundle.getString("alergia"));
                    this.editTextProfissao.setText(bundle.getString("profissao"));

                }
            }
    }

    public void confirmar (View view){
        this.usuario.setNome(this.editTextNome.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setData(this.editTextData.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setRg(this.editTextRg.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setCpf(this.editTextCpf.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setDoenca(this.editTextDoenca.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setAlergia(this.editTextAlergia.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.setProfissao(this.editTextProfissao.getText().toString());
        this.usuario.confirmar();

        Toast.makeText(this,this.usuario.get_messagem(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(usuario._status)
            finish();
    }

    public void cancelar (View view){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Classe `Usuario`:

```
public class Usuario extends _default {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String data;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private String doenca;
    private String alergia;
    private String profissao;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getDoenca() {
        return doenca;
    }

    public void setDoenca(String doenca) {
        this.doenca = doenca;
    }

    public String getAlergia() {
        return alergia;
    }

    public void setAlergia(String alergia) {
        this.alergia = alergia;
    }

    public String getProfissao() {
        return profissao;
    }

    public void setProfissao(String profissao) {
        this.profissao = profissao;
    }

    public Usuario(){
        super();
        this.id = -1;
        this.nome = "";
        this.data = "";
        this.rg = "";
        this.cpf = "";

        this.doenca = "";
        this.alergia = "";
        this.profissao = "";
    }

    public ArrayList<Usuario> getLista(){
        BD bd = new BD();
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ResultSet resultSet = bd.select("SELECT * FROM usuario");
            if(resultSet != null ){
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    Usuario obj = new Usuario();
                    obj.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    obj.setNome(resultSet.getString("nome"));
                    obj.setData(resultSet.getString("data"));
                    obj.setRg(resultSet.getString("rg"));
                    obj.setCpf(resultSet.getString("cpf"));
                    obj.setDoenca(resultSet.getString("doenca"));
                    obj.setAlergia(resultSet.getString("alergia"));
                    obj.setProfissao(resultSet.getString("profissao"));
                    lista.add(obj);
                    obj = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;

        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void confirmar(){
        String comando = "";
        if(this.getId() == -1){
            comando = String.format("INSERT INTO Usuario(nome, data, rg, cpf, doenca, alergia, profissao) values ('%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s' );",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao());

        }
        else
        {
            comando = String.format("UPDATE Usuario SET nome ='%s', date = '%d', rg = '%s', cpf = '%s', doenca = '%s', alergia = '%s', profissao = '%s' WHERE id = %d;",
                    this.getNome(), this.getData(), this.getRg(), this.getCpf(), this.getDoenca(), this.getAlergia(), this.getProfissao(), this.getId());
        }
        BD bd = new BD();
       bd.execute(comando);
       this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;
    }

    public void apagar(){
        String  comando =  String.format("DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = %d ", this.getId());

        BD bd = new BD();
        bd.execute(comando);
        this._messagem = bd._messagem;
        this._status = bd._status ;    
    }    
}
```

Classe `UsuarioAdapter`:

```
public class UsuarioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Usuario> lista;

public UsuarioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> lista)
    {
        super(context,0,lista);
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final Usuario itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.item_lista,null);
        final View layout = convertView;

        TextView textViewNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        textViewNome.setText(itemPosicao.getNome());

        TextView textViewData = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
        textViewData.setText(itemPosicao.getData());

        TextView textViewRg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRg);
        textViewRg.setText(itemPosicao.getRg());

        TextView textViewCpf = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCpf);
        textViewCpf.setText(itemPosicao.getCpf());

        TextView textViewDoenca = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDoenca);
        textViewDoenca.setText(itemPosicao.getDoenca());

        TextView textViewAlergia = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAlergia);
        textViewAlergia.setText(itemPosicao.getAlergia());

        TextView textViewProfissao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfissao);
        textViewProfissao.setText(itemPosicao.getProfissao());

        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEditar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Novo.class);
            intent.putExtra("nome", itemPosicao.getNome());
            intent.putExtra("data", itemPosicao.getData());
            intent.putExtra("rg", itemPosicao.getRg());
            intent.putExtra("cpf", itemPosicao.getCpf());
            intent.putExtra("doenca", itemPosicao.getDoenca());
            intent.putExtra("alergia", itemPosicao.getAlergia());
            intent.putExtra("profissao", itemPosicao.getProfissao());
            context.startActivity(intent);
           }
        });
    Button buttonDeletar = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonApagar);
        buttonDeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemPosicao.apagar();
                if (itemPosicao._status)
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(context, itemPosicao.get_messagem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            });

        return convertView;  
    }
}
```

### Classes do BD

Classe `ExecuteBD`:

```
public class ExecuteBD extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResultSet>{
    private Connection connection;
    private String query;

    public ExecuteBD(Connection connection, String query) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.query = query;
    }


    @Override
    protected ResultSet doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try
        {
            resultSet = connection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());

        }finally {
            try
            {
            connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Classe `BD`:

```
public class BD extends _default implements Runnable {
    private Connection conn;
    private String host = "192.168.0.100";
    private String db = "android";
    private int port = 2345;
    private String user = "androidUser";
    private String pass = "*android*";
    private String url = "jbdc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s";

    public BD (){
        super();
        this.url = String.format(this.url, this.host, this.port, this.db);

        this.conecta();
        this.disconecta();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pass);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;

        }
    }
    private void conecta(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        try
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
            this._status = false;
        }
    }

    private void disconecta(){
        if(this.conn != null ){
            try
            {
                this.conn.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            }finally {
                this.conn = null;
            }
        }
    }
    public ResultSet select (String query){
        this.conecta();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            resultSet = new ExecuteBD(this.conn, query).execute().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._status = false;
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    public ResultSet execute (String query){
        this.conecta();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            resultSet = new ExecuteBD(this.conn, query).execute().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("PrivateWalletM", e.getMessage());
            this._status = false;
            this._messagem = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Classe `Lista`:

```
package com.example.matheus.privatewalletm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;


    public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listViewUsuario;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);

        this.listViewUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUsuario);
        this.listViewUsuario.setAdapter(new UsuarioAdapter(this, new Usuario().getLista()));
    }


}
```

Imagem da tabela do BD:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, verifique se o id do seu botão está instanciado corretamente no seu XML.

Comment: Dica coloque um break point na linha         final Usuario itemPosicao = this.lista.get(position); e veja se não esta null algum dos campos referenciados.

Comment: Pela stacktrace, o erro tá aqui (UsuarioAdapter, linha 60): layout.setVisibility(View.GONE); Acho que o layout tá vindo nulo porque o convertView é vazio. Dá uma debugada pra ver se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Bom eu tentei arrumar aqui, e acontece o seguinte: quando eu abro minha aplicação sem estar conectada com o banco de dados a activity é chamada normalmente, mas quando conectada ao banco a aplicação simplesmente trava

Answer (score 1):

Na sua classe DB acho que o atributo url está errado. Você declarou:

```
private String url = "jbdc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s";
```

Mas teria que ser:

```
private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://%s:%d/%s";
```

Comment: Qual a diferença entre elas?

Comment: O início da string "jbdc" está errado, deve começar com "jdbc", creio que o problema seja este.

Comment: Verifiquei uma dúzia de vezes e não consegui ver a diferença.:)

Comment: Era este o problema? Funcionou? Quando conseguir testar poste um comentário aqui.

Comment: Ricardo, não fui eu que coloquei a pergunta:)